# Doctrine - PostgreSQL - Uppercase and Spaces in Table / Field names

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, doctrine-orm

Having issues with Doctrine 2.3 and PostgreSQL with Spaces and Upper case Field / Table names

Example: ( Yes we are working on migrating away from this )

```
SELECT "Field Name"
FROM "Table Name"
```

We also have a mix of the two formats

```
SELECT "Field Name", another_field_name
FROM "Table Name", another_table_name
```

When using doctrine I'm getting a PDOException. When looking at the error I see that there are no double quotes around Fields / Tables ( names ) that have Upper case and Spaces.

Is there a fix? Workaround?

Here is an example of what Doctrine is generating

```
SELECT t0.TheId AS theid1, t0.Name AS name2, t0.User AS user3
FROM The Table t0 
WHERE t0.TheId = 1234
```

Here is how I need it

```
SELECT t0."TheId" AS theid1, t0."Name" AS name2, t0."User" AS user3
FROM "The Table" t0 
WHERE t0."TheId" = 1234
```

Comment: That is a horrible naming style. Doctrine will not be the only tool to have problems with that. Although it *is* "legal" in SQL, it still isn't a good idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I agree 100% and we are trying to move away from this legacy data structure, but need to support this right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to use backticks to let Doctrine know that it should be quoted: [Quoting reserved words](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words). E.g:

```
<?php
/** @Column(name="`number`", type="integer") */
private $number;
```

Comment: I'm generating these, is there and option for this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the accepted answer won't work in the presented situation.  The backticks will not work as every column in a doctrine query gets an alias by using the lower cased name with an appended identifier. This alias would have spaces in it and would therefore generate a sql error when passed to postgres.

The only way this could be corrected is in Doctrine itself when the query is generated.

update it seems this may have been corrected in the latest version of doctrine2.  It now replaces non acceptable characters.