# Symfony: Doctrine cannnot find table with first letter Uppercase

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have this database in which all tables have this format:

> Somedata

and the names of the columns are like this:

> UserInformation

Basically, the first letter is capitalized, and Doctrine cannot find the table/column

I tried adding a naming strategy:

```
naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

But that didn't work.

I also tried to set MySQL lower case table names to 1

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

That didn't work as well. If I change all the names of the tables and columns to lowercase, works as expected. However, I cannot do that in the production database, so how can make Doctrine find the tables with that format?

By the way, the tables are already created, and I cannot modify them

Comment: Please accept the existing answer or add an answer with your solution. In any case, please remove the solution from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Found the solution. I had to write the table name in the Entity like this:

```
@ORM\Table(name="`Somename`")
```

Source:

> [**Doctrine - PostgreSQL - Uppercase and Spaces in Table / Field**
>   **names**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807902/doctrine-postgresql-uppercase-and-spaces-in-table-field-names)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices here:

1. Implement custom naming strategy where you generate table names as you wish. Check the docs [Doctrine Naming Strategy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/namingstrategy.html)
2. Set desired table name in every entity: `@ORM\Table(name="SomeName")`

Comment: I have it like this: * @ORM\Table(name="Somename") but same problem. Table not found

Comment: By the way, the tables are already created, and I cannot modify them

Comment: Show corresponding error message and talbe annotation.

Comment: Also try to clear the cache completly (e.g. removing everything inside `var/cache/*`).

Comment: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: no existe la relación «somename»

Comment: Table annotation:

 * @ORM\Table(name="Somename")

Comment: I already removed everything from cache. As soon as I rename the table from "Somename" to "somename", everything works, but I cannot do that, because it is a database to another application

Comment: Try to execute raw sql `SELECT * FROM Somename` if you get same error then it is an issue related to `lower_case_table_names`

Comment: Found the solution. I had to write it like this: (name="`Somename`")

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807902/doctrine-postgresql-uppercase-and-spaces-in-table-field-names

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 6, you should use `#[ORM\Table("Somename")]`. It should be used like that:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SomenameRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table("Somename")]
class Somename {
   // here all your fields
}
```